# Mostrar relaciones de una iteración ya de relaciones

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Buenos días estoy iterando unos registros en una vista que son los cliente, esta iteración ya se conecta a una relación que en este caso me saca todos los productos que tiene este cliente, estos productos son inmuebles y tienen una Provincia y un Municipio y aquí es donde me encuentro el problema.

**Vivienda**

| id | name | municipio | provincia | cliente_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Reformado con plaza de garaje incluida | 350 | 598 | 1 |
| 2 | Reformado con ascensor | 355 | 598 | 1 |

**Provincia**

| id | provincia |
| --- | --- |
| 598 | Valencia |
| 620 | Barcelona |

**Municipio**

| id | provincia_id | municipio |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 350 | 598 | Alfafar |
| 355 | 598 | Sedavi |

**Cliente**

| id | nombre |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Mariano |
| 2 | Roberta |

**Entonces primero itero toda mi tabla clientes**

```
$clientes = Cliente::with('inmuCliente')->get(); //Aquí ya le estoy añadiendo la relación de las propiedades que tiene este cliente con inmuCliente

@foreach ($clientes as $item)  
   ....
   ....
   //Aquí itero las propiedades que tiene el cliente
   @forelse ($item->inmuCliente as $prop)
      <h5>//Aquí tiene que ir la Provincia y el mmunicipio</h5>
   @empty
      <div class="alert alert-warning editalert" role="alert" style="font-size: 13px;">
         No tiene inmuebles
      </div>
  @endforelse
@endforeach
```

**Mi modelo Cliente**

```
protected $primaryKey='id'; 
protected $table = 'cliente';

public function inmuCliente()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Vivienda::class, 'cliente_id');
}
```

Entonces no se como hacer que me ponga el nombre de la Provincia y del Municipio.

Comment: ¿En la tabla tienes declaradas las refencias a la tabla municipio y provincia?

Comment: No comprendo tu pregunta @FranCámara  que tabla? y que referencias?

Comment: Disculpa que no me haya explicado bien, en el model de Vivienda deberías tener una referencia hasOne a los model de Provincia y de Municipio al igual que en el model de Cliente tienes el de Vivienda, así: public function inmuCliente() { return $this->hasMany(Vivienda::class, 'cliente_id'); }
Si los tienes, has probado a acceder así: $item->inmuCliente()->municipio() y $item->inmuCliente()->provincia();
No tengo la documentación de Laravel a mano, si no me explicaría mejor.

Comment: Vale ahora probare lo que me dices, pero seria adecuado que lo publicaras en una respuesta, voy a probar gracias

Comment: Tendrá que ser más tarde, que ahora mismo no puedo, pero la publicaré para que quede más claro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

creo que el error esta en el forelse en la cual se deber cambiar el forelse por un foreach

puede utilizar la funcion de  var_dump(); para imprimir todo el array en plano o sacar como json, se recomienda utilizar la extension de https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/json-formatter/bcjindcccaagfpapjjmafapmmgkkhgoa

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
  $clientes = Cliente::with('inmuCliente.inmuMunicipio','inmuCliente.inmuProvincia')->get(); //Aquí ya le estoy añadiendo la relación de las propiedades que tiene este cliente con inmuCliente
    
    
    var_dump($clientes);//me permite imprimir todo el array en un plano y saber que datos me traer
    return response()->json(true);//si quiere puede traer los datos en json 
    
    @foreach ($clientes as $item)  
        @foreach ($item->inmuCliente as $client)
            echo "<h5>$client->municipio</h5>";//obtener el id
            echo "<h5>$client->Provincia</h5>";////obtener el id
    
            echo "<h5>$client->inmuMunicipio->municipio</h5>";//obtener el nombre
            echo "<h5>$client->inmuProvincia->provincia</h5>";////obtener el id
    
    
        @endforeach
    @endforeach





    //archivo de modelos 
    **texto en negrita**
    //model cliente
    class Cliente extends Model{
        public function inmuCliente(){
            return $this->hasMany(Vivienda::class, 'cliente_id');
        }
    }
    //model Vivienda
    class Vivienda extends Model{
        public function inmuMunicipio(){
            return $this->belongsTo(Municipio::class, 'municipio');
        }
        public function inmuProvincia(){
            return $this->belongsTo(Provincia::class, 'provincia');
    
        }
    }
```

Comment: Funciona perfecto @marcosalbertosaavedrasanabr muchisimas gracias

Answer (score 1):

En la vista debes mostrar parametros no relaciones,es decir que en el modelo la relacion es **inmuCliente**
pero si quieres acceder desde la vista a esta relacion automaticamente el CamelCase se convierte a camel_case  osea **inmu_cliente**, de echo en las ultimas versiones no es necesario llamar el metodo with para poder cargarlas en el blade,solo llamando la relacion puedes obtener los datos,si lo que quieres es mandar los datos a otro lado que no sea una vista ahi si usas el metodo laod()

```
 @forelse ($item->inmu_cliente as $prop)
      <h5>//Aquí tiene que ir la Provincia y el mmunicipio</h5>
   @empty
      <div class="alert alert-warning editalert" role="alert" style="font-size: 13px;">
         No tiene inmuebles
      </div>
  @endforelse
```